# Licencing development virtual machines

Tags: licensing, virtual-machine

I prefer to my development work in a virtual machine so my computer don't get messy and slow.
However, I always deal with the issue of licencing, even if the windows version on my host and on my VM is the same.

Is there a way to pay less than buying a full licence for every VM I have?

Comment: you should ask on server fault. Those guys understand licensing...

Comment: The developers are here. I thought maybe there is other solution that I don;t know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and pricing, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about OS licensing or tools licensing?   If this is Windows OS licensing, then MSDN is an easy way to have lots of spare licenses.